# Searching for part of string within another string in dataframe

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataset which looks something like this:

```
long_name x y short_name
Adhesion G protein-coupled receptor E2 (ADGRE2) 10 10 ADGRE2
Adhesion G-protein coupled receptor G2 (ADGRG2) 12 12 ADX2
ADM (ADM) 13 13 ADM
ADP-ribosyl cyclase/cyclic ADP-ribose hydrolase 1 (CD38) 14 14 ACH1
```

What I want to do is create an additional column which will state whether or not the value of `short_name` is in the value of `long_name` to produce a TRUE/FALSE (or present/not) value in a new column.

I saw some advice on here about using the `grepl` function for looking for a bit of a string within another string. The issue I'm having is trying to iterate it over the whole file.

I have something like:

```
for (row in 1:length(nrows(combined_proteins))){

  long_name = proteins[1]
  short_name = proteins[4]

  if grepl(short_name, long_name) = TRUE{

   proteins$presence = "Present"

   else proteins$presence = "Not"
  }
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work and I'm not really sure whether this is even the smartest way to go about it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way of solving this is to use the `ifelse` function and `str_detect` from the stringr package.

```
proteins<-read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=
"long_name x y short_name
'Adhesion G protein-coupled receptor E2 (ADGRE2)' 10 10 ADGRE2
'Adhesion G-protein coupled receptor G2 (ADGRG2)' 12 12 ADX2
'ADM (ADM)' 13 13 ADM
'ADP-ribosyl cyclase/cyclic ADP-ribose hydrolase 1 (CD38)' 14 14 ACH1"
)

library(stringr)
proteins$presence<- ifelse( str_detect(proteins$long_name, proteins$short_name ) , "Present",  "Not")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, exactly the sort of thing I was after. And obviously much more elegant than the script I was originally trying to work with.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues with your `for` loop. You want to either iterate from `1:nrow()` or `1:length()`. The `length(nrow())` will almost always return 1. Your `if` statements need to have parentheses so it should be `if(boolean){return values}else{other return value}` If the name of your data frame is `proteins` then the following should work.

```
for (row in 1:nrow(proteins)){

  print(proteins$long_name[row])
  long_name = proteins$long_name[row]
  short_name = proteins$short_name[row]

  if (grepl(short_name, long_name)){
    proteins$presence[row] ="Present"
  } else { 
    proteins$presence[row] = "Not"
  }
}
```

you can also do the same by using the `tidyverse` packages `dplyr` and `purrr`. `purrr` provides functions to iterate through multiple columns at the same time.

```
proteins %>%
  dplyr::mutate(short_in_long = purrr::map2_lgl(short_name, long_name, function(x, y){
    grepl(x, y)
  }))
```

Comment: While I didn't actually actually use this option, instead used the ifelse option suggested by Dave2e. Part of that though is that I don't really follow what this line of code is doing. What do the different options/commands here do?